# Why could this dropzone.js not be uploading to a live server?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dropzone.js

This implementation of dropzone.js works on my local host, but when I move it to live the files don't end up on the server:

Here's the form:

```
<form action="submit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

<label for="fname">First name: </label>
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" required />          

<label for="lname">Surname:</label>
<input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" required />
        
<div class="dropzone" id="file-upload"></div>
            
<button type="submit" id="submit-all">Submit</button>

</form>
```

I am using AJAX to submit the form:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  Dropzone.options.fileUpload = {
    url: '/submit.php',
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    paramName: 'file',
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 1,
    maxFiles: 1,
    maxFilesize: 10,
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*,.mp4,.mkv,.avi',
    addRemoveLinks: true,

    init: function() {
      dzClosure = this; 
   
      document.getElementById("submit-all").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
 
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        dzClosure.processQueue();

      });

      this.on("sendingmultiple", function(data, xhr, formData) {
        formData.append("fname", jQuery("#fname").val());
        formData.append("lname", jQuery("#lname").val());

      });
    }
  }

    });

});
```

submit.php

```
<?php

require_once "db.php";

$target_dir = "uploads/";

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][0], $target_dir.$_FILES['file']['name'][0])) {
$status = 1;
echo 'uploaded, ';
}
else {
echo 'not uploaded, ';
}

echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";

$fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['fname']);
$lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lname']);


if(mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO CF_form(fname, lname
) VALUES('" . $fname . "', '" . $lname . "')")) {
 echo 'sent';
} else {
   echo "Error: " . $sql . "" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

As I said, this all works on my local host but on the live site the file doesn't appear. I get the 'sent' message and the debugging info is like this:

```
uploaded, Here is some more debugging info:
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => IMG_1129.JPG
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/jpeg
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /tmp/phpriOyPQ
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2181000
                )

        )

)
sent
```

The uploads directory is set to 777. Just can't figure out why I'm not getting the files.

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I have added error reporting, but it shows no errors.